# OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.com:443

Tags: git, ssl, openssl, gitlab

I try to clone my repo from GitLab to my local folder. 
I am on Windows 10 and using Git bash for Windows 10.
I created a folder and enter the command : `git clone https://gitlab.com/x.x.x.git`

and I get this error : `fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/x.x.x.git/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.com:443`

I don't know if I get this error because I have a wrong use of Git (it's my first time using it), or it has something to do with my SSL version or something else related ?
Something to know is I am behind a proxy, do you think it can be origin of the problem ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just having this issue.

In my case it was because git was using my global git user settings, but for this particular repo I had been given access under a different email address.

The solution was to set my user information for the repo to use the right email address.

In SourceTree, I clicked the 'Settings' button in the top-right, then the 'Advanced' tab, then I unchecked 'Use global user settings', and then I changed the value in the 'Email address' input box.

[image]

Comment: Thankx for you answer. I tried a similar way and it worked !

Comment: Same error I am getting in VS-2019 when i tried to clone the Repository. I set valid email in Visual studio global settings but no luck.